# IntervalSlider[] stops working after using Locator[]

Tags: plotting, dynamic, gui-construction

`Dynamic` `IntervalSlider[]` on a `DateListPlot[]` loses ability to change `PlotRange` after using `Locator[]`.

If you start by adjusting the interval slider, everything works fine. The `DateListPlot[]` updates as the slider changes.

However, once you change the location of the epilog plot with the locator, the interval slider stops working as intended and the plot no longer dynamically updates with its values.

The interval slider code was from Mathematica examples on interval slider, and the locator epilog was from a search on plot within plot.

```
DynamicModule[{interval, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax, d, pt = {3706819200, 0.5}},
 d = Transpose[{DateRange["Jan 1 2017", Today], 
    RandomReal[1, Length@DateRange["Jan 1 2017", Today]]}];
 {xmin, xmax} = AbsoluteTime /@ d[[{1, -1}, 1]];
 ymin = Min[Last /@ d];
 ymax = Max[Last /@ d];
 Column[{
   Show[
    DateListPlot[d, ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> {
       Dynamic[
         Locator[Dynamic[pt],
         Plot[{-1, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 10}, Background -> None, 
          Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Green]]
       ]}],
    PlotRange -> {Dynamic[interval], {ymin, ymax}}
    ],
   IntervalSlider[Dynamic[interval], {xmin, xmax, 1}, ImageSize -> {400, 30}, MinIntervalSize -> 1]
   }]
 ]
```

Is there something I'm missing here or is this a bug?

*Edit*

Also just tried it with `Dynamic[Inset[]]` and it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 3):

First of all `Locator[ Dynamic @ pt, ...]` should work without `Dynamic` on top. Somehow it is not the case in `Epilog` so I usually put it in a separate `Graphics` in `Show`. For your case it matters even more because otherwise `Plot` needs to be recalculated while you are moving it.

Please try to narrow things down and report it to WRI Support. There is something fishy going on, once the `Locator` is moved, the `PlotRange` is overwritten, so your inner `Dynamic` vanishes. Putting `Dynamic` on top: 
 `PlotRange -> Dynamic[...]` prevents that.

Another problem is that as soon as `Locator` is touched the `PlotRangePadding` is effectively set to `0`. To fix it one needs to use `PlotRangePadding -> Dynamic[..., None]`.

Putting things together:

```
DynamicModule[
  {interval, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax, d, pt = {3706819200, 0.5}}
, d = Transpose[{DateRange["Jan 1 2017", Today], RandomReal[1, Length@DateRange["Jan 1 2017", Today]]}]
; {xmin, xmax} = AbsoluteTime /@ d[[{1, -1}, 1]]
; ymin = Min[Last /@ d]
; ymax = Max[Last /@ d]

; Column[
    { Show[
        DateListPlot[d, ImageSize -> Large]
      , Graphics[{
          Locator[Dynamic @ pt
          , Plot[{-1, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 10}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Green]
          ]
        }]
      , PlotRange -> Dynamic@{interval, {ymin, ymax}}
      , PlotRangePadding -> Dynamic[Scaled[.05], None]        
      ]
    , IntervalSlider[Dynamic[interval], {xmin, xmax, 1}
      , ImageSize -> {400, 30}, MinIntervalSize -> 1
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```